# I am tring to get all data from this month and the Previous month so I can compare the % change

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart

I am making a fitness app where users can log their sets using the following schema:

```
  static Future<void> createTables(sql.Database database) async {
    await database.execute("""CREATE TABLE sets(
      id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
      exercise_name TEXT,
      total_weight TEXT,
      total_reps TEXT,
      date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      is_favorite INTEGER 
      )
      """);
  }
```

Now I need two functions where I can return data from this current month and the previous month using the date but it isnt working:

```
//this will return a list of maps
//gets called when app is launched and will get all our shit from the database
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getTodayItems() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //get connection
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(now);
    return db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date = ?', [formattedDate]);
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getThisMonthItems() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //get connection
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String query = "select * from sets where date <= DATE('now', '-1 month')";
return db.rawQuery(query);
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getLastMonthtems() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //get connection
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(now);
    return db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date = ?', [formattedDate]);
  }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what isn't working exactly and what you have tried? You didn't really give any context. Make sure you check out [how to make a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that others can help you.

Comment: In the getThisMonth funciton im trying to return all of the sets in teh past month but its returning empty for me

Comment: Your code for the 3 functions is exactly the same! Is it normal?
`getThisMonthItems ` and `getLastMonthtems ` return the same dataset as `getTodayItems`

Comment: Because I have not been able to use this in the getThisMonthItems() as it returns null

Comment: String query = "select * from sets where date <= DATE('now', '-1 month')";
    return db.rawQuery(query);

Answer (score 1):

For current day use this SQL:

`SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of day') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');`

For current month:

`SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');`

For last month:

`SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now','start of month','-1 month') AND datetime('now', 'start of month');`

Comment: Hi i have placed your queries in a string like so :   String query = 'SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');';         but its tell me its expects a ;

Comment: That's normal you should use `"` for the string: 
``String query = "SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');";``

Comment: Hi your answer works perfect excpet when its the first of the month. Why is that?

Comment: Can you explain what is not working?

Comment: Its returing empty because today is the first of the month

Comment: You mean for current month?

Comment: yes if fixed it with an if else but it would be good for the question to find the route cause

Comment: Try like this: 
`SELECT * FROM sets WHERE date BETWEEN datetime('now', 'start of month', 'start of day') AND datetime('now', 'localtime');`

Comment: I tried it, it is still ignoring all records from the first of May

Comment: In fact now its only returning records from today not even the 2nd of May anymore